# IPv6 support for Azure

Tags: azure, networking, ip, azure-web-app-service, ipv6

My hosting provider supports IPv6 for quite some time now. I am looking in to the possibility to migrate to Azure, but would like to know if IPv6 is supported on Azure. Is there any documentation available?

Comment: On May 5th, Microsoft committed some code into the Azure PowerShell project, indicating that support for IPv6 might arrive soon. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/2178/files

Answer (score 6):

To quote the Azure faq:

> Microsoft has played a leading role in helping customers to smoothly
>   transition from IPv4 to IPv6 for the past several years. To date,
>   Microsoft has built IPv6 support into many of its products and
>   solutions like Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2. Microsoft is
>   committed to expanding the worldwide capabilities of the Internet
>   through IPv6 and enabling a variety of valuable and exciting
>   scenarios, including peer-to-peer and mobile applications.
>
> The foundational work to enable IPv6 in the Azure environment is well
>   underway. However, we are unable to share a date when IPv6 support
>   will be generally available at this time. For more information on IPv6
>   technologies and IPv6 support available in the Windows operating
>   system today, see Microsoft’s IPv6 information site which includes
>   business, technical, and developer resources:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb530961

Hope this helps!

Comment: Azure has some _broken_ support for vnets for virtual machines, Ok support for cdn, other than that it is still mostly non existing or just broken.

Answer (score 5):

Although there was an announcement of IPv6 support at Ignite 2016, there are some limitations that you need to know when working with Azure VM:

- The public IPv6 addresses **cannot** be assigned to a VM. They can only be assigned to a load balancer.
- The IPv6 endpoint on the VM is not exposed directly to the internet. It is behind a load balancer.
- You may not upgrade existing VMs to use IPv6 addresses. You must deploy new VMs.

[Visit here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-ipv6-overview/) for more info

Answer (score 2):

We don't use VMs in Azure, our solutions are all pure App Service (aka WebApp) to host our ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI projects.

We've had several apps rejected by Apple when submitted due to lack of ipv6 support from our side, which is [mandatory by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html). [Microsoft's official post about Apple's demand for ipv6](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-mobile-apps-supporting-ipv6-and-the-apple-submission-process/) is lousy and doesn't cut the reality of the situation.

We solved this by moving our DNS to [Cloudflare supports ipv6](https://www.cloudflare.com/ipv6/). It automagically channels ipv6 traffic over Azure's ipv4 back and forth. Just make sure you enable Cloudflare "cloud" on DNS entries that work over Azure AppServices.

You can verify it works or not before submitting to Apple and waste time waiting by visiting the following ipv6 test sites:

- http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php
- http://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just created a VM on Azure. Only got an RFC1918 IPv4 address and a link-local IPv6 address. So no, you don't really have publicly routable IPv4 or IPv6 to your end host, you'll have some sort of 6-to-4 hack via their load balancers.

To be fair though, AWS EC2 has similar issues.

If you want native public IPv4/IPv6 direct to your end host/VPS, perhaps use another cloud VPS hosting provider that guarantees that, such as Digital Ocean.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft [announced at Ignite 2016](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-networking-announcements-for-ignite-2016/) that support for IPv6 "for applications and services hosted on Azure Virtual Machines" is now available.